# Looking at a frequency reassignment rule as a Möbius transform

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Suppose we have some Schwartz function $h$. Denote its Fourier transform $\widehat{h}$. Let $\xi_0$, $a$, $\Delta$ be positive and fixed.

I have a function $\Omega: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{C}$. This is

\begin{align} \Omega_h(t,\eta)&=\frac{\xi_0 \widehat{h}(\eta-\xi_0)+a(\xi_0+\Delta) e^{2\pi i \Delta t} \widehat{h}(\eta-\xi_0-\Delta)}{\widehat{h}(\eta-\xi_0)+a e^{2\pi i \Delta t} \widehat{h}(\eta-\xi_0-\Delta)}\\ &= \xi_0 +\frac{\Delta}{1+\frac{\widehat{h}(\eta-\xi_0)}{a e^{2\pi i \Delta t} \widehat{h}(\eta-\xi_0-\Delta)}}\\&=\xi_0+f\left(\frac{\widehat{h}(\eta-\xi_0)}{e^{2\pi i \Delta t} \widehat{h}(\eta-\xi_0-\Delta)}\right)\end{align} where $$f(z) = \frac{\Delta}{1+\frac{z}{a}}\tag{1}\label{466381_1}$$ is a Möbius transform when $\Delta\neq 0$ and $|a|<\infty$. Note that this is only valid when the denominator of the first line is nonzero, let's assume so.

**I am interested in understanding the dependence of $\Omega_h(t,\eta)$ on $a$ and $\Delta$**, which is the reason I write $\Omega_h(t,\eta)$ above as a sum of $\xi_0$ and some Möbius transform (in hopes that looking at this thing as a Möbius transform might give me some nice properties). My intuition of the problem tells me that if I look at $\Omega_h(t,\eta)$ for some fixed $t$, and when $\eta\approx\xi_0$, then $\Omega_h(t,\eta)$ should be close to $\xi_0$ and MAYBE when $\eta\approx\xi_0+\Delta$, then $\Omega_h(t,\eta)$ should be close to $\xi_0+\Delta$, or close to $\xi_0$ if $\Delta$ is sufficiently small.

I am trying to see if there are any nice properties of the Möbius transform that can help me understand this dependence. One thing I tried exploring was the fixed points of this Möbius transform. The fixed points of \eqref{466381_1} are $$z=\frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2+4a\Delta}}{2}$$ which implies that we have a fixed point of this Möbius transform when $$\frac{\widehat{h}(\eta-\xi_0)}{\widehat{h}(\eta-\xi_0-\Delta)}=\frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2+4a\Delta}}{2}e^{2\pi i\Delta t}.$$ I don't think there is a nice way to write the ratio of the Fourier transform of a function at two different frequency shifts, so I am not sure if I can even uncover what $\eta$ gives a fixed point (when thinking of $t$ as fixed). Regardless though, this doesn't help me in understanding the dependence of $\Omega_h(t,\eta)$ on $a$ and $\Delta$.

Any thoughts/ideas about how to uncover such dependence would be greatly appreciated.